# MudBlazor: How to add button to top App bar?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I use this MainLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
  
          <MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@darkModeActive" Theme="currentTheme" />
          <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="ButtonOnClick">@ButtonText</MudButton>
            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Filled.Brightness4" Color="Color.Default" />
...
```

And do not see a button but only as on image
[image]

What is incorrect? How to fix it?

It is Blazor Server App project. I have made the same in Blazor Webassembly project - it works fine

Comment: Are both projects the same .NET version?

Comment: Yes, it is NET 6.  I have found the reason. I have missed to include    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> becuase server app has different files

Answer (score 0):

The both projects NET 6. I have found the reason.
I did not include  because Blazor server app and Blazor webassembly have different files: _Layout.cshtml/_Host.cshtml and index.html